# Pessoal, alguém sabe como chama ou realizar essa técnica no Android estúdio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

Quero fazer um APP para academia e necessito usar uma tela menor na frente da tela principal como é demonstrado no print de um APP já existente que tá em anexo. Quero deixar o fundo desfocado e mostrar uma tela menor na frente com o que quero. Alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer ou onde procurar? Agradeço.

[image: imagem para exemplo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa "técnica" é o `AlertDialog`, ela vem no próprio Android e é bem fácil de ser implementada, por padrão ele apenas permite título, texto e três tipos de botões (positivo, negativo e neutro), mas você pode personalizar criando seu próprio layout `.xml` e o inflando e configurando manualmente. Link da documentação: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=pt-br. E aqui um ótimo tutorial que explica como usar o Alert "padrão" ou como personalizá-lo: https://www.devmedia.com.br/android-dialog/26749

Comment: Caramba, cara. Obrigado. É exatamente isso.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void alertaexemplo(int position) {
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("meu titulo")
    .setMessage("Mensagem")
    .setPositiveButton("sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //Ação// 
        }
    })
    .show();
```

}

Um exemplo bem simples que você pode editar conforme sua necessidade!
E se vc estiver usando o Android Studio pode baixar um código de exemplo.